# Convert SQL Server Cursor To MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, function, cursor

How to convert a SQL Server cursor to MySQL?

```
ALTER function [dbo].[Terlambat](@proses int) returns @tempKK table (krk int,terlambat int) as 
begin
declare @uid int, @total_hari_kerja int
select @total_hari_kerja = SUM(alokasi)  from proses 
declare krk_uid cursor for select distinct krk from kartu_kendali where proses <= 8
open krk_uid
fetch next from krk_uid into @uid
while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
insert into @tempKK select top 1 krk, dbo.GetTerlambat(realisasi_tgl_terima, @total_hari_kerja) terlambat from kartu_kendali where proses = 1 and krk = @uid order by RecID
fetch next from krk_uid into @uid
end 
close krk_uid
deallocate krk_uid
return 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing a cursor to MySQL that has no cursor you should follow this solution:

1. Add a [*Row Number*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895110/4519059) to your `SELECT` statement that help you to fetch data from your `SELECT` over it.
2. Now, you can use a variable that starts with 1 and grows inside the `WHILE` in each step by 1 and filter your `SELECT` statement over *Row Number* and this variable.